# WebPartVerbRenderMode = "Menu" works fine in IE but not in any other browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, web-parts

WebPartZone verb rendering mode (`WebPartVerbRenderMode = "Menu"`) works fine in IE but not in any other browser.

As I see the problem since 2005 (http://forums.asp.net/t/939974.aspx). I would be wonder if there is any way to have dropdown verb menu for firefox and chrome.

Comment: Sadly the web part stuff is kind of obsolete. It didn't get much adoption back then and I do not think anyone cared to support it after that. After all the Chrome project wasn't even started when the Web Parts were written.